# Declaring a null statement in swift

Tags: swift-playground

I have been working my way around a game in swift and just want to create this statement:

```
if (player1!=null)||(player2!=null)
    println("You are out of the game")
```

I've already declared a variable for `player1` and `player2` but how do I go around this?

Answer (score 0):

Write it in Swift instead of C:

```
if player1 != nil || player2 != nil {
    println("You are out of the game")
}
```